# MySQL utf8 VARCHAR size

Tags: mysql

If I have a MySQL column `VARCHAR(1024) utf8`, and I store plain English characters, what kind of size will this consume? Will it take 3 bytes per character or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe wrong but VARCHAR(1024) = 1024 characters if you're the one who set the 1024